# Using Python in pandas.read_sql from ODBC - UnicodUnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-16-le' codec can't decode bytes in position 34-35: illegal UTF-16 surrogate

Tags: python, sql, pandas, utf-16le

I get this error when I include certain fields in a query. I have looked at other solutions on the same error and not quite finding what I need or at least understanding how.
Any other solutions to this problem?

[image]

To give more context on what I am doing: I have connected to two separate databases. I plan to query from DB1 first as a Data Frame (DF1), then from DB2 as DF2 to make calculations using pandas to DF1 based on DF2. Finally inserting new data to DB2.